# laravel voyager just stay loading and doesn't work

Tags: php, laravel, voyager

laravel voyager doesn't work, it just stays loading like this

[image: screenshot]

Browser console log
[image: Console log]

**PHP version:** 8.0.6

**Laravel version:** 8.57.0

Comment: Check your browser console and the laravel logs in `storage/logs` for any errors.

Answer (score 0):

*I am not sure about you but in my case, I changed a compiled file manually instated of changing the source file and then compiling it.*

Hance go to theme folders.

```
cd resources/views/themes/tailwind
```

Then re-compile it.

```
npm run dev
```